# Output from controller to HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Can someone please tell me how to output data from my controller to an HTML form. I want to change the label of an anchor from "Like" to "Liked" if the user has already clicked the link previously.

Here is the HTML.

```php
<section class="row posts">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-3-offset">
        <header><h3>other posts</h3></header>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <article class="post">
                <p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
                <div class="info">Posted by {{ $post->user->username }} on {{ $post->created_at }}</div>
                <div class="interaction">
                    <a href="#" class="like" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">Like</a>
                    @if(auth()->user() === $post->user)
                        |
                        <a href="#" class="edit" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">Edit</a> |
                        <a href="{{ route('post.delete',['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </article>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <script>
        var token = '{{ session()->token() }}';
        var urlLike = '{{ route('like') }}';
    </script>
</section>
```

The JavaScript to get the `postid` from the form:

```
...
$('.like').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        postId = event.target.dataset.postid;
        var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling==null ? true:false;
        $.ajax({
           method: 'POST',
           url: urlLike,
           data: {isLike: isLike, postId: postId, _token: token}
        })
        .done(function () {
            //change the page
        })
    })
...
```

The route:

```
Route::post('/like',[
        'uses' => 'PostController@postLikePost',
        'as' => 'like'
    ]);
```

Finally, can someone please tell me how to send the output from the controller to the HTML form?

```php
public function postLikePost(Request $request)
{
    $post_id = $request['postId'];
    $is_like = $request['isLike'] === 'true' ? true : false;
    $post = Post::find($post_id);
    if (!$post) {
        return null;
    }
    $user = Auth::user();
    $like = $user->likes()->where('post_id', $post_id)->first();

    if ($like) { // user already liked the post
        $like->delete();

        return null; // output to "Like" in the html form here
    }

    $like = new Like();
    $like->post_id = $post->id;
    $like->user_id = $user->id;
    $like->save(); // output to "Liked" in the html from here

    return null;
}
```

The label of the Like anchor should change from Like to Liked if the user has already like the post.

Comment: where is your response from the controller? also you'll need to setup your ajax request.

Comment: @AdityaThakur I want to write instructions to change Like to Liked from the commented sections of the controller. Let's say that if an user already liked a post, it will be recorded in the database and Like will be changed to Liked. Now if the same user clicks the Liked button again, I need to verify that the record already exists in the database and remove it (so I have to fetch the unique id of the post from html and check the database and send data back to html) Not sure how to do both at the same time...

Comment: Can one setup an ajax request to POST and GET at the same time?

Comment: i've posted an example, of how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up both as POSTs and then in your `success` block query the result and set to either `like` or `liked`. Something like:

```
success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "Liked";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this, change it as per your need though.

```
public function postLikePost(Request $request)
{
  $post = Post::where('id', $request->get('post_id'))->first();
  if(!$post){
    return response()->json(['status' => 1, 'message' => 'post not found']);
  }
  if($post->liked == 1)//change it as per your model
  { 
    return response()->json(['status' => 2, 'message' => 'already liked']);
  }
  $post->status = 1;
  $post->save();
  return response()->json(['status' => 3, 'message' => 'liked']);
}
```

and in your ajax success

```
success: function(response){
  if(response.status == 1){
   window.alert('Post Not Found')
  }
  else{
   document.querySelector('#likeBtn').innerHTML = 'liked'
  }
```

like button

```
<a href="#" class="like" id="likeBtn" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">Like</a>
```